# It's there max groups limit in std::regex of C++?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

here is the code:

It's find when there are 31 groups:

```
try
{
    regex re("(0)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)(a)(b)(c)(d)(e)(f)(g)(h)(i)(j)(k)(l)(m)(n)(o)(p)(q)(r)(s)(t)(u)", tr1::regex::icase);
}
catch (regex_error e)
{
    std::cout << e.what();
}
```

However, I try to add one more group (total 32 groups), oops:

```
try
{
    regex re("(0)(1)(2)(3)(4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)(a)(b)(c)(d)(e)(f)(g)(h)(i)(j)(k)(l)(m)(n)(o)(p)(q)(r)(s)(t)(u)(v)", tr1::regex::icase);
}
catch (regex_error e)
{
    std::cout << e.what();
}
```

a regex_error exception is caught and print

> regular expression error

I use VisualStudio 2010 on Windows 7

It seems there is max limit of groups. How can I break the limit?

Comment: Just curious: Why would you want that many groups in a single regex?

Comment: Split up functionality, multiple methods, possibly multiple (understandabke) regexps

Comment: Are you writing an HTML parser?

Comment: @Cerbrus I try to match some education organization email addresses, but not all EDU organization have "edu" in their email addresses. So I try to specify those addresses in regex and I find this trouble.

Comment: I still don't see why you need that many groups. You could just do something like: `@(edu|school|uni|lib)\.(com|net|edu|org)`

Comment: @Cerbrus some addresses don't contain "edu", such as example@imperial.ac.uk, Imperial College.

Comment: @Celebi I think it is better to give some examples of your address..to give you the best regex

Comment: Come on guys, he's justified this enough. It's a valid C++ question, and I suspect the answer is that it's a Microsoft bug. Someone used `unsigned int` as a bitset. Perhaps the limit cannot be broken.

Comment: @Celebi: Then add `imperial.co.uk` to the regex, like this: `@(edu|school|uni|lib|imperial)\.(com|net|edu|org|co.uk)`. Basically, add _all_ the possible extensions.

Comment: @Potatoswatter assuming it is a bug , but knowing this does the resolve the problem of the OP?

Comment: @agstudy If it's not a Microsoft bug, then there may be a way within the language to resolve it. The first thing to do is RTFM.

Comment: Hmm, nope, it must be a Microsoft bug. That exception can only be thrown if the expression is invalid by the selected semantics. The default semantics refer to ECMAScript 3; ECMAScript 3 says there isn't a limit. Many web developers would be upset with such a regex engine :P

Comment: I was getting the same exception and you question helped me find the root cause. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about the windows version but the gcc version only has partial support

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011

Its section 28 your looking at. Other languages seem to be able to match more groups

maybe try a differnt engine ?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines